# How is this background image implemented?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I looked at this stunning landing page at [offset](http://www.offset.com/) and was wondering how this background image is implemented? I do not see sth. like `background-image:url('paper.gif');` in the code. Do you have any idea how the image is implemented in the site?

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Uh, the background is declared for the body element, no? It gos like `url(/images/v2/grid_invitepage_fade.jpg) center 150px repeat-x #000 !important`

Comment: @Terry I really like your own page! You used a wordpress theme. Which one?

Comment: It's a custom theme ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
background: url(/images/v2/grid_invitepage_fade.jpg) center 150px repeat-x #000!important;
}
```

at:
http://www.offset.com/stylesheets/app_min/new_homepage.min.css?v=0.6.40

Answer (score -1):

Good question. It's in the CSS. As the guy pointed out above. Look at it's stylesheet.